# UICollectionView didDeselectItemAt not get triggered

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I have a `UICollectionView`, and when selecting an item `didDeselectItemAt` not get triggered, but when selecting an other item, the first will get triggered. Why?

This is have method is implemented:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let userSetting = userSettings[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    selectedUserSettingRecordName = userSetting.id
    containerViewController!.performSegue(withIdentifier: "message", sender:self)

}
```

There is no view above the `collectionView` which could interfere.

Comment: didSelect vs did**De**select?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didSelectRowAtIndexPath returns wrong IndexPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118993/didselectrowatindexpath-returns-wrong-indexpath) This question is on `UITableView` and not `UICollectionView`, but the system/reason is the same.

Comment: It one of everyone's favorite mistakes: to mix uр `didDeselectItemAt` and `didSelectItemAt`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

is not

**didDeselectItemAt - is called in second time, if you select the any item after that it will call**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```

it is

**didSelectItemAt - is called in first time, if you select the any item  it will call**

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
```